# Spring-Mvc - JdbcDaoSupport Error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, jdbctemplate

I am getting the following error:

```
[C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat-6.0\webapps\crimeTrack\WEB-INF\classes\com\crimetrack\jdbc\JdbcCountryDAO.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1385)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
```

**jdbcDAOCountry.java**

```
@Repository
public class JdbcCountryDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport implements CountryDAO{

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  

    public List<Country> getCountryList() {
        int countryId = 6;
        String countryCode = "AI";
        logger.debug("In getCountryList()");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM TBLCOUNTRY WHERE countryId = ? AND countryCode = ?";
        logger.debug("Executing getCountryList String "+sql);

        Object[] parameters = new Object[] {countryId, countryCode};

        logger.info(sql);

        //List<Country> countryList = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,new CountryMapper());

        List<Country> countryList = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, parameters,new CountryMapper());
        return countryList;
    }



    public void saveCountry(Country country) {
        logger.debug("In saveCountry");

        String sql= "INSERT INTO crimetrack.tblcountry (countryName, countryCode) " + 
                    "VALUES (:countryName, :countryCode)";

        logger.debug("Executing saveCountry String " + sql);
        int count = getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,new MapSqlParameterSource()

                .addValue("countryName", country.getCountryName())
                .addValue("countryCode", country.getCountryCode()));
        logger.debug(count +" Rows affected in tblCountry");


    }

    public void updateCountry(Country country) {
        logger.debug("In updateCountry");

        String sql= "UPDATE crimetrack.tblcountry SET countryName = :countryName, "+
                    "countryCode = :countryCode WHERE countryId = :countryId";

        logger.debug("Executing updateCountry String " + sql);
        int count = getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("countryId",country.getCountryId())
                .addValue("countryName", country.getCountryName())
                .addValue("countryCode", country.getCountryCode()));
        logger.debug(count +" Rows affected in tblCountry");

    }

    public static class CountryMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<Country>{

         public Country mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Country country = new Country();
                country.setCountryCode(rs.getString("countryCode"));
                country.setCountryId(rs.getInt("countryId"));
                country.setCountryName(rs.getString("countryName"));
                return country;
            }       
    }

}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
         xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 



<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->              

    <bean id="countryManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.CountryManager">
        <property name="countryDao" ref="countryDao"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="countryDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcCountryDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.AuthenticationManager">
        <property name="loginDao" ref="loginDao" /> 
    </bean>    
    <bean id="loginDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcLoginDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->  

    <bean id="divisionManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.DivisionManager">
        <property name="divisionDao" ref="divisionDao"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="divisionDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcDivisionDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

     <bean id="positionManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.PositionManager">
        <property name="positionDao" ref="positionDao"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean id="positionDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcPositionDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>    

<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean id="genderManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.GenderManager">
        <property name="genderDao" ref="genderDao"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="genderDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcGenderDAO" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ --> 

    <bean id="officerRegistrationValidation" class="com.crimetrack.service.OfficerRegistrationValidation">

            <property name="validateUserNameManager" ref="validateUserNameManager"/>


    </bean>

    <bean id="validateUserNameManager" class="com.crimetrack.service.ValidateUserNameManager">
            <property name="officerDao" ref="officerDao"/>

    </bean>


    <bean id="officerDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcOfficersDAO" >
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ --> 

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource" /></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>





  </beans>
```

**servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<!-- __________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->    

     <!-- Supports annotations and allows the use of @Controller, @Required, @RequestMapping -->
    <context:annotation-config/>    

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crimetrack.jdbc"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crimetrack.service"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.crimetrack.web" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure the `applicationContext.xml` has the bean `dataSource` defined.

The **DAO** should pass a constructor-arg and not a property since `dataSource` is a constructor-arg.

Annotate a constructor method and ensure it accepts a `dataSource`.

The dataSource passes is the same one defined in the `applicationContext.xml`:

```
 <bean id="countryDao" class="com.crimetrack.jdbc.JdbcCountryDAO">
     <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>

@Repository
public class JdbcCountryDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport implements CountryDAO {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    JdbcCountryDAO(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    public List<Country> getCountryList() { 
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it after several hours of Googling.

Comment: great to know this helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is that no dataSource or jdbcTemplate is wired into the JdbcCountryDao bean:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required

However your XML config shows that you have the dataSource sent, so are you sure that this error occurs when using the posted version of the file?

Also, there is no need to have declare a `@Autowired jdbcTemplate` in a class that extends `JdbcDaoSupport` as the superclass provides this for you already.

Comment: Do i need to create a DataSource class and then preform @Autowired

Comment: Remove `@Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;` from the JdbcCountryDao.

Comment: I am now getting :org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcCountryDAO' defined in file [C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat-6.0\webapps\crimeTrack\WEB-INF\classes\com\crimetrack\jdbc\JdbcCountryDAO.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required.......java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required

Comment: Don't think you answered the question in my first answer - *are you sure that this error occurs when using the posted version of the file*?

Comment: yes it is happening on the posted version every time i make a change i redeploy to the server, if thats what your asking

Comment: i am using  <context:annotation-config/> so i think its not reading the mappings for the datasource from the applicationContext.xml file

Comment: how do you load applicationContext.xml? Do you have ContextLoaderListener set up in web.xml?